# Wordpress Plugin needs Jquery Datepicker and Timepicker in Admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Working on a simple plugin that adds a couple of custom fields to a custom post data type. The field is a JQuery timepicker and datepicker. I do not know where the problem is. Here is my function and the custom field. Please point me in the right direction and let me know what is missing or how can I get it work.

```
//FUNCTION TO ADD SCRIPTS TIMEPICKER JQUERY PLUGIN
function tek_tour_script(){
    ?>
<script>
JQuery('#slider_example_1').timepicker({
    hourGrid : 4,
    minuteGrid : 10,
    timeFormat : 'hh:mm tt'
});

JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    JQuery('#MyDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});

</script>
<?php
wp_register_script('tek_tour_timepicker', plugins_url('/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('tek_tour_timepicker', plugins_url('/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', dirname(__FILE__)));

wp_register_script('tek_tour_sliderAccess', plugins_url('/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('tek_tour_sliderAccess', plugins_url('/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js', dirname(__FILE__)));

wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'tek_tour_script' );
```

Here are my divs:

```
 <h3>Times</h3>
<br>
<div>
<input type="text" name="slider_example_1" id="slider_example_1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="MyDate" name="MyDate" value=""/>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
function tek_tour_time_css(){
?>
<style>
.ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.ui-timepicker-div dl {
    text-align: left;
}
.ui-timepicker-div dl dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.ui-timepicker-div dl dd {
    margin: 0 10px 10px 45%;
}
.ui-timepicker-div td {
    font-size: 90%;
}
.ui-tpicker-grid-label {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.ui-timepicker-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl dt {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl dd {
    margin: 0 45% 10px 10px;
}
 </style>
 <?php
 }
 add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts','tek_tour_time_css');
```

Thank you!!

Comment: It's better to use it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869120/does-wordpress-provide-native-datepicker-in-admin

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code is not correct, the timepicker needs to be inside the jQuery(document).ready(),

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
    jQuery('#slider_example_1').timepicker({
        hourGrid : 4,
        minuteGrid : 10,
        timeFormat : 'hh:mm tt'
    });
});
```

You also need to create a JS file for it and enqueue it because echoing it directly in the "admin_enqueue_scripts" or "enqueue_scripts" action as a  will give an error because jQuery is not loaded in WordPress by then.

And you should also add dependency of your JS code with the jQuery library. Also do specify the dependencies of your other libraries to ensure that they load after the jQuery library.

It is also a good practice to add all your CSS and JS as a separate file and enqueue them using wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script() respectively instead of directly echoing or printing them.

Example:

```
wp_register_script('tek_tour_sliderAccess', plugins_url('/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script('tek_tour_sliderAccess');
```

Reference:
[Wordpress Codex wp_enqueue_script() - Script Dependency](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery)